# Изменяется константа в ReactJS + HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Есть файл с компонентом, который участвует в головном файле с маршрутами Router.
В файле есть импорт константы, которая является двумерным массивом:

import {defaultPositions} from '../consts/board';

В конструкторе в state базовое значение равноценно константе

FIGURES_POS: DEFAULT_POSITIONS

Проблема следующая:
при обновлении состояния компонента - меняется и константа, даже при переходе на другую страницу приложения с помощью HashRouter. Только при реальном обновлении страницы она принимает исходное состояние.
Как избавиться от этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приветствую

Не совсем понятно, почему вы импортируете `defaultPositions`, а в компоненте используете `DEFAULT_POSITIONS`. Если допустить, что это одна и также переменная, и учитывая, что мы не видели ваш код, возможно проблема заключается в том, что, так как объекты в js передаются по ссылке, а не по значению, в каком-то месте вы мутируете её значение.

Чтобы этого не допустить, можно или в каждом компоненте использующем эту переменную копировать её значение, или, что безопаснее, запретить экпорт самой переменной, а вместо неё экспортировать функцию, которая будет возвращать скопированное значение.

Чтобы скопировать значение, так как у вас массив массивов (это не двумерный массив, кстати), надо делать deep clone. То есть или использовать библиотеку типа  https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep или написать свою функцию

```
const cloneDeep = (arr: any[][]) => arr.map(x => x.map(y => y))
```

если вложенные элементы - объекты, то и их надо копировать

```
const cloneDeep = (arr: any[][]) => arr.map(x => x.map(y => {...y}))
```

Надеюсь я вас правильно понял